# SwiftUI AsyncImage in TabView is not showing

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode13

Images are shown without TabView but not with TabView.

Also, I got the log below in Debug Console

> [UICollectionViewRecursion] cv == 0x107829812 Disabling recursion trigger logging

How can I fix it?

```swift
TabView {
    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "link"))
    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "link"))
}.tabViewStyle(.page)
.frame(height: 300)
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the `AsyncImage` into a `ZStack` makes it work as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69908541/image-doesnt-appear-with-asyncimage-in-swiftui). The reason for this is not obvious to me and I would assume it is an issue with `AsyncImage`. In any case it works with `VStack` and `HStack` as well. Using a simple `View` with `AsyncImage` as content or putting it in a `Group` didn't work for me.