# Image doesn't appear with AsyncImage in Swiftui

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-asyncimage

I have AsyncImage inside a TabView. When I do this the image never appears. I just see the progress bar.

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)

struct TEST: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            TabView {
                
            
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://blckbirds.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/pexels-kammeran-gonzalezkeola-6128227-2.jpg"), scale: 2) { image in
                        image
                          .resizable()
                          .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    } placeholder: {
                        ProgressView()
                            .progressViewStyle(.circular)
                    }
                
            }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
            
        }//V
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try using a `ZStack` to wrap the `AsyncImage`, like this, works for me:

```
struct TEST: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView {
                ZStack {   // <--- here
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://blckbirds.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/pexels-kammeran-gonzalezkeola-6128227-2.jpg"), scale: 2) { image in
                        image
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    } placeholder: { ProgressView().progressViewStyle(.circular) }
                }
            }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Yup, that worked. Just that simple. Thanks!

Comment: That didnt work for me. I wonder why. That is very weird...

Answer (score 0):

I am new to SwiftUI. I copied the `@workingdog support`'s code and it worked well. But I think there is some glitch with the preview and I am not sure this an unknown issue or not.

With the original code, I can only see the loading view, not matter I close and re-open the preview window. Then I added a frame for the image view. I can see the image being properly loaded by changing frame size to something else then change it back, e.g. 300 -> 350 -> 300.

```
struct ExampleImgItem: View {
    var body: some View { 
    `workingdog support`'s code
}


struct ExampleImgItem_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExampleImgItem()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .leading)
    }
}


P.S. I am using Xcode 13.3.1,
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue. My solution is to add

```
.aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 6, height: 9), contentMode: .fill)
.scaledToFit()
```

to TabView.